# Does Lipschitz continuity of a convex imply boundedness of the domain of its Fenchel conjugate

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, lipschitz-functions

Let $g:\mathcal{H} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a convex and $L_{g}$-Lipschitz continuous function on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Is the domain of its Fenchel conjugate $g^*$, where
$$
g^*(y) := \sup_{x \in \mathcal{H}} \{ \langle y, x \rangle - g(x),
$$
bounded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the domain of its Fenchel conjugate is bounded. In particular
    \begin{equation}
  \text{dom} \, g^* \subseteq B(0,L_{g}),
\end{equation}
    where $B(0,L_{g})$ denotes the ball with radius $L_{g}$ around the origin.

First note that for every Lipschitz continuous function
  \begin{equation}
\lVert g(x) \rVert \le \lVert g(x) - g(0) \rVert + \lVert g(0) \rVert \le C + L_g \lVert x \rVert, \quad \forall x \in \mathcal{H}
  \end{equation}
  for some constant $C > 0$.
  Thus, for any $y \in \mathcal{H}$ with $\lVert y \rVert > L_g$ and any $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}_+$,
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
g^*(y) = \sup_x \{ \langle y, x \rangle - g(y) \} \ge& \langle y, \lambda y \rangle - g(\lambda y) \\
                                               \ge& \lambda \lVert y \rVert^2 - \lambda L_g \lVert y \rVert - C \\
=& \lambda \lVert y \rVert \left( \lVert y \rVert - L_g \right) - C,
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation} 
proofing that $g^*(y) = +\infty$ by letting $\lambda$ go to $+\infty$.